Exporting report i have a PDf of 0 byte
I use use Active report 10 and in my asp page i have an ActiveReportsWeb:WebViewer.
I’d like export my report by a custom button.
When i click on button i have just a file of 0 Bytes.
In my custom button i tryed to insert :
Dim MyPDF As New GrapeCity.ActiveReports.Export.Pdf.Section.PdfExport
    Try
        MyPDF.Export(WebViewer1.Report.Document, _path_and_name)
    Catch _Error As Exception
    End Try

I try to export it when i load the page but i have the same results.
Thank you
Luca

It is a bad idea to catch and then ignore exceptions. It might have given you a clue about what is going wrong.

I removed the code that caught the error to make the code easier to read. There are no errors when running. Thank you

If you have the exception then you should include it in the question.

I change the code and in the catch i insert just : LabMsg.Text = _Error.Message

I forgot to add rpt.run()  in the load page.
